# If $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets, then $(A \cup B) − C = (A − C) \cup (B − C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove: $(A \cup B) − C = (A − C) \cup (B − C)$

The left side is the set that is either in $A$ or $B$ or both but not in $C$. The right side is the set in $A$ that doesn't contain $C$ or the set in $B$ that doesn't contain $C$. The Venn Diagram for this seems straightforward. But how would I perform a written proof.

I think this is a two part proof. First prove the left side implies the right, then that the right side implies the left.

How would I go about doing this exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algebraic proof that uses indicator functions.

Recall that the indicator function $1_A$ of a set $A$ satisfies $1_A(x) = 1$ when $x \in A$ and $1_A(x) = 0$ otherwise.

It is easy to check that $1_{A \cup B} = \max(1_A, 1_B)$ and $1_{A\setminus B} = \max(0, 1_A -1_B)$.

Then we have
\begin{eqnarray}
1_{(A \cup B) \setminus C} &=& \max(0,1_{A \cup B}-1_C ) \\
&=& \max(0, \max(1_A, 1_B) - 1_C) \\
&=& \max(0, \max(1_A-1_C, 1_B-1_C)) \\
&=& \max(0, \max(0, 1_A-1_C), \max(0,1_B-1_C)) \\
&=& \max(\max(0, 1_A-1_C), \max(0,1_B-1_C)) \\
&=& 1_{(A \setminus C) \cup (B \setminus C)}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

$$(A\cup B)\backslash C=(A\cup B)\cap C^c=(A\cap C^c)\cup(B\cap C^c)=(A\backslash C)\cup (B\backslash C)$$

Comment: What is $C^c$? It may not be a set.

Comment: it's the complement of $C$

Comment: Complement with respect to what?

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea is right; if you prove the following two statements:
$$x \in L \rightarrow x\in R$$
$$x\in R\rightarrow x\in L$$
where $L$ and $R$ are the left and right sides of the equality, that suffices to show that $L=R$. For instance, suppose
$$x\in (A\cup B)-C$$
does it follow that $x\in (A-C)\cup(B-C)$? Or equivalently, that $x$ is in either $A-C$ or $B-C$?

Answer (score 0):

My favorite method for problems such as these is to write out the two sides of the equation in set notation. For example, the LHS is
$$(A \cup B) - C = \{x \mid (x \in A \vee x \in B) \wedge x \not \in C\}.$$
My next step is to use the arithmetic of $\vee$ and $\wedge$ to expand the expression $(x \in A \vee x \in B) \wedge x \not \in C$. Recall that $\wedge$ distributes over $\vee$, so we get $(x \in A \vee x \in B) \wedge x \not \in C = (x \in A \wedge x \not \in C) \vee (x \in B \vee x \not \in C)$. So
$$(A \cup B) - C = \{x \mid (x \in A \vee x \in B) \wedge x \not \in C\} = \{x \mid (x \in A \wedge x \not \in C) \vee (x \in B \vee x \not \in C)\} = (A - C) \cup (B - C).$$